# getting a checkbox value in spring controller

Tags: spring-mvc

[image]

hi  i want the multiple marked checkbox value in spring controller to perform multiple delete task in spring, how to get these values of marked checked box as shown in figure

here is jsp page which shows list of department detail and i have given the checkbox option to delete multiple department 
here is my jsp page

```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script>
    function setAction(url) {

        if (url == 'FindByDepartmentID') {
            document.form.action = "/EmployeeWebSpring/department/FindByDepartmentId";

        }
        if (url == 'FindByDepartmentName') {
            document.form.action = "/EmployeeWebSpring/department/FindByDepartmentName";
        }

    }
    function showMe(it) {

        var hasChecked = false;
        var chks = document.getElementsByName('checked');
        var vis = '';

        for ( var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
            if (chks[i].checked) {
                hasChecked = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (hasChecked == false) {
            vis = "none";
        } else {
            vis = "block";
        }

        document.getElementById(it).style.display = vis;

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form:form name="form" commandName="departmentForm" method="post">
        <c:if test="${requestScope.x}">
            <div id="div1">
                <center>
                    Department_ID:<br />
                    <form:errors path="departmentId" />
                    <br /> <br />
                    <form:input path="departmentId" />
                    <br /> <input type="submit" name="FindByDepartmentID"
                        value="FindByDepartmentID" id="FindByDepartmentID"
                        onclick="setAction(this.id)" />
                </center>
            </div>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${requestScope.y}">
            <div id="div2">

                Department_Name
                <form:input path="departmentName" />
                <input type="submit" name="method" value="FindByDepartmentName"
                    id="FindByDepartmentName" onclick="setAction(this.id)" /> <br />
                <font size=3>For Searching the employees by<b>Employee
                        Name</b><br />you can use % match all the records with the given
                    pattern
                </font><br /> <font size="2"> <i>e.g <b> for search by</b>EmployeeName<br />
                        matches alL the employees whose name starts with character <b>S</b></i></font>
            </div>
        </c:if>

        <c:if test="${departmentName}">
            <div>
                <fmt:message key="searchResult.header" />
                <br>
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${empty requestScope.listDepartmentBO}">
                        <fmt:message key="searchResult.noresult" />
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <table border="2">
                            <tr>
                                <th width="118">Delete</th>
                                <th width="118">Department_ID</th>
                                <th width="118">Department_Name</th>
                                <th width="118">Department_Location</th>
                                <th width="118">detail_Link</th>
                            </tr>
                            <c:forEach var="departmentBO"
                                items="${requestScope.listDepartmentBO}">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><form:checkbox path="departmentId"
                                            value='${departmentBO.departmentId}' onclick="showMe('div1')" id="checked"/></td>

                                    <td>${departmentBO.departmentId}</td>

                                    <td>${departmentBO.departmentName}</td>

                                    <td>${departmentBO.departmentLocation}</td>
                                    <td><a
                                        href="javascript:loadId(${departmentBO.departmentId})"><font
                                            color="blue">Details</font></a></td>


                                </tr>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </table>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>

                <br />
                <fmt:message key="searchResult.searchAgain" />
                <a href="/EmployeeWebSpring/search/searchspring"> <fmt:message
                        key="searchResult.click" />
                </a>

            </div>
        </c:if>
        <div id="div1"
            style="position: absolute; width: 600px; display: none;">
            <input type="submit" name="create" value="delete" align="middle"
                style="size: 100px" />
        </div>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

and and this is my controller delete function right now its performing single delete task

package com.nousinfo.tutorial.controllers;
 import java.util.Map;

```
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.nousinfo.tutorial.model.DepartmentForm;
import com.nousinfo.tutorial.service.impl.DepartmentServiceImpl;
import com.nousinfo.tutorial.service.model.DepartmentBO;

@RequestMapping("departmentController")
public class DepartmentController {
    private DepartmentServiceImpl departmentServiceImpl;

    public DepartmentServiceImpl getDepartmentServiceImpl() {
        return departmentServiceImpl;
    }

    public void setDepartmentServiceImpl(
            DepartmentServiceImpl departmentServiceImpl) {
        this.departmentServiceImpl = departmentServiceImpl;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/departmentForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String view(Model model) throws Exception {
        DepartmentForm departmentForm = new DepartmentForm();
        model.addAttribute("departmentForm", departmentForm);
        return "departmentForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/createDepartment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createEmployee(@Valid DepartmentForm departmentForm,
            BindingResult bindingResult, Map<String, DepartmentForm> model)
            throws Exception {
        String form = null;
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "departmentForm";
        }

        model.put("departmentForm", departmentForm);
        departmentForm.setUpdateStatus("A");
        if (departmentForm.getUpdateStatus().charAt(0) == 'A') {
            boolean flag = departmentServiceImpl
                    .actionDecider(convertDeptFormToDeptBO(departmentForm));
            if (flag == false)
                form = "DBError";
            else
                form = "Success";

        }
        return form;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteDepartment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String deleteDepartment(
            @ModelAttribute("departmentForm") DepartmentForm departmentForm) {
        String form = null;
        departmentForm.setUpdateStatus("D");
        if (departmentForm.getUpdateStatus().charAt(0) == 'D') {
            boolean flag = departmentServiceImpl
                    .actionDecider(convertDeptFormToDeptBO(departmentForm));
            if (flag == false)
                form = "DBError";
            else
                form = "Success";

        }
        return form;
    }

    private DepartmentBO convertDeptFormToDeptBO(DepartmentForm departmentForm) {
        DepartmentBO departmentBO = new DepartmentBO();
        departmentBO
                .setUpdateStatus(departmentForm.getUpdateStatus().charAt(0));
        departmentBO.setDepartmentId(departmentForm.getDepartmentId());
        departmentBO.setDepartmentName(departmentForm.getDepartmentName());
        departmentBO.setDepartmentLocation(departmentForm
                .getDepartmentLocation());

        return departmentBO;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is in your jquery loop build a list of the department IDs:

```
    for ( var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
        if (chks[i].checked) {
            list.add(getDepartmentId());
        }
```

Then pass that in to your controller method via an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: deleteDepartment,
  type: 'POST',
  data: list
  })
  .done(function() {
    console.log("success");
  });
```

In your controller method include the list of IDs as a requestParam:

```
deleteDepartment(@RequestParam List<String> list, @ModelAttribute("departmentForm") DepartmentForm departmentForm)
```

and inside your controller method do a query to delete all records where the department id is inside the list you passed in.